# replace strings in array with bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I need to work with bash only and im new to it

```
#!/opt/bin/bash
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
array=($(mysql --host=xxxx --user=xxxx --password=xxxx -s -N -e 'use xbmc_video; SELECT strFilename FROM movie, files WHERE files.idFile=movie.idFile ORDER BY idMovie DESC LIMIT 10;'))
```

This produces an array of filenames with spaces within since im working on windows samba shares.  Question is how can I delete last 4 symbols in every string to get rid of extensions without having to bother which ext is that I want to get pure file names

Answer (score 6):

Add this to the end of your script:

```
for i in ${!array[@]}; do
    array[i]="${array[i]%%.???}"
done
```

Two tricks were used here:

1. The list of an array indexes: `${!array[@]}` ([see info](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays#metadata))
2. The pattern cut-off from the end: `"${array[i]%%.???}"` (must be in double quotes because of the spaces in the file names) ([see info](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe?s%5B%5D=replace#search_and_replace))

To ensure (later when you use the array) that you get the whole name of the file use the following trick in the loop:

```
for file in "${array[@]}"; do  # the double-quotes are important
    echo "$file"
done
```

For more info see [the bash hackers site](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/) and the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/)

Comment: thank You for that - I guess I still miss the whole concept

tho now when filename got commas within hes name, the trick fails. Nothing happens to that filename

Comment: I've edited the pattern replacement method to 'cut the end counting from the end' (see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe?s[]=replace#substring_removal)

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a couple of options.  First, you could edit off the file extensions as part of the command that generates the array in the first place:

```
array=($(mysql --host=xxxx --user=xxxx --password=xxxx -s -N -e 'use xbmc_video; SELECT strFilename FROM movie, files WHERE files.idFile=movie.idFile ORDER BY idMovie DESC LIMIT 10;' | sed 's/[.]...$//'))
```

(note that this assumes 3-letter extensions.  If you need to trim any-sized extensions, change the sed command to `sed 's/[.].*$//'`)

Second, you can trim the extensions from the entire array like this:

```
trimmedarray=("${array[@]%.???}")
```

(again, this assumes 3-letter extensions; for any size, use `"${array[@]%.*}"`)